# General strategy for working out the torsion of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma(t)$ be a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}$ with nowhere vanishing curvature.
Then denoting $\frac{d}{dt}$ by a dash, its torsion is given by $$\tau = \frac{(\gamma' . \gamma^{''}).\gamma'''}  {||\gamma '. \gamma''||^2}$$

Lets say I have the curve $$\gamma(t)=(5(1+t), 2(t), t)$$

Do I then just work out the derivatives and plug it into $\tau$?

Where does the exact value of the torsion come from then?

Comment: What do you mean ? The torsion you wrote down doesn't make any sense .. Are you interested to know where the torsion of a curve comes from?

Comment: Why bit of the torsion doesn't make sense? It is straight out of the book Andrew Pressley elementary differential geometry.

Comment: Your symbols just doesn't make sense.. I mean the torsion of a curve $c$ is $$\tau(t)=\frac{(c',c'',c''')}{\Vert c'\times c''\Vert^2},$$ where $(c',c'',c''')$ is the mixed product.

Answer (score 2):

The torsion of a space curve is $$\tau(t)=\frac{det(c',c'',c''')}{\Vert c'\times c''\Vert^2}=\tau(t)=\frac{(c'\times c'').c'''}{\Vert c'\times c''\Vert^2},$$
In this case : $$\tau(t)=0$$
or without using these formulas : $$c(t)=(5,0,0)+t(5,2,1)$$
it is clear that $c(t)$ is a parametrization of a straight line, then it's torsion is zero.